Create Xcframework for swift package manager which has dependency of another swift package manager
IOS: I am creating my own swift package manager. In that I have dependency for PubNub SDK.
dependencies: [      
.package(url: "https://github.com/pubnub/swift.git", from: "7.0.0")             
 ]

Now the requirement is to create xcframework for swift package manager with dependency.  In xcframework how to add pubnub depedency?
I tried to create xcframework using third party library :
https://github.com/unsignedapps/swift-create-xcframework
when I use this xcframwork to the xcode project, It's giving error for PubNub. so seems it's not getting added in xcframwework.

Binary Frameworks cannot depend on Swift Packages according to WWDC 2019 (416). You can try the following steps:

Build the PubNub target for each platform you want to include in your .xcframework. Here's an example of how to do it for iOS and iOS Simulator respectively in Debug configuration. You can repeat the same steps for Release configuration with your code signing.

# iOS Simulator
xcodebuild -target PubNub -scheme PubNub -configuration Release -arch x86_64 -arch arm64 -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-alias-module-names-in-module-interface" -derivedDataPath build

# iOS devices
xcodebuild -target PubNub -scheme PubNub -configuration Release -arch arm64 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-alias-module-names-in-module-interface" -derivedDataPath build


Create the final .xcframework according to the results received in the previous step. I had to add allow-for-internal-distribution flag to workaround the issue mentioned here. The workaround with setting allow-internal-distribution is no longer present because setting -alias-module-names-in-module-interface for OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS in the steps above solves this issue.

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PubNub.framework -framework build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PubNub.framework -output PubNub.xcframework 


Next, create a new Xcode target (select Framework template) and add PubNub.xcframework under the Link Binary with Libraries section as a dependency. As I did in the first step, you can build your newly created target for different platforms.


That's not working for me. If I create archive before creating xcframework files are not getting generated

Did you archive your project from the Xcode editor or the command line? Meanwhile, here's the XCFramework you can download from the Assets section: https://github.com/pubnub/swift/releases/tag/7.2.0
